Redshift Spectrum Unload Batch Sizes
I am working on an archiving solution to reduce the data size in Redshift datawarehouse. So, for this I want archived data to be stored in s3 in a structured way (based on partition) since in some cases we would also be querying this data using Spectrum functionality. So for this operation, I decided to do my unloads in a batch manner as I have ~1 Billion records in the table:
UNLOAD ('SELECT CAST(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM createdat) AS INT) AS year, CAST(EXTRACT(MONTH FROM createdat) AS INT) AS month, * FROM schemaname.tablename WHERE createdat >= ''2023-09-01 00:00:00+00'' AND createdat < ''2023-10-01 00:00:00+00''') TO 's3://s3-path/archive/schemaname/tablename/' IAM_ROLE 'arn:aws:iam::x:role/xx' PARTITION BY (year, month) PARALLEL OFF FORMAT AS PARQUET;
and such that, when I am attaching partition this is how my table would look like
ALTER TABLE s3_extended.schemaname__tablename ADD PARTITION (year=20xx, month=1) LOCATION 's3://s3-path/archive/schemaname/tablename/year=20xx/month=1/';
For every 1 month data, there will be one upload query but the data distribution in my tables is not even, for some months it is <100 while for some >1Million records are there. How can I make the batches be distributed in a better way.
I want to know a better way to distribute this data in batches. How can I make the batches be distributed in a better way?

The question back is “better for what?”  IMHO When using Spectrum you want to reduces the amount of data that needs to be passed back to Redshift to complete the queries.  You also want to maximize the number of Spectrum workers you can use and apply good WHERE clauses and aggregation that can be applied by Spectrum.
